# How to delete mail from server after download with IMAP using Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, imap

I would like for my webmail to delete my mail after Thunderbird downloads it (I have it set to IMAP not POP; correction from original wording), so that I will only be storing my mail on my machine.

However I can't figure out how to set this. All of the help I searched up references an account setting that isn't available on the version I have. (38.1.0/OSX). I've seen people reply to those walk throughs with the same issue I'm having, but haven't been able to turn up a solution or anything more recent than 2013. I'm an above average user but I'm not advanced. Is there something I have to do on the cpanel of my webmail to enable this? Or do I do it in Thunderbird?

Comment: It looks like to created two accounts.  You can freely edit your own posts, but only as the user who created it.  Multiple user IDs will interfere with that and also mess up your accumulation of rep.  See http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts to get your accounts merged.

Comment: Ah thanks for this. Workflow for anyone else who needs to change from IMAP to POP is here https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/faq-changing-imap-pop

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:** If you are using IMAP (according to your updated question) then this is not possible. It's not how IMAP works. IMAP is designed to communicate with a central server where all your mail is stored. This allows multiple email clients to easily collect and process your email while keeping everything synchronised. What you see on your local desktop is just a local "copy" that is synchronised with this central server.

If you want to download your email to a single desktop computer and remove it from the server then you need to connect to your mailbox using POP3 and then following the instructions below.

Unfortunately in Thunderbird you can't simply change an account from using IMAP to POP3, you will need to add a new POP3 account in Thunderbird with the appropriate POP3 settings.

Using **POP3**, in Thunderbird, under the "Server Settings" for the account in question, make sure that "Leave messages on server" is unchecked.

[image: Server Settings - Leave messages on server]

Providing you are accessing your email via POP3 then there should be no other server-side settings (ie. cPanel) that require configuration.

Comment: @fixer1234 Ha, that does change the question somewhat! I've updated my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also drag copies of your messages from your email client to a folder, to store them for later reference. Then delete those same ones from the client itself, which will free up space on your server.