# Thunderbird : moving emails from a "virtual folder" to my "local folders" does removes those emails from server

Tags: email, thunderbird, archiving

I want to archive emails (IMAP) from year 2021 - which means I want to copy them to a local folder, and have them removed from my Gmail account.

I've setup a **virtual folder** on *all emails from my GMAIL account*, filtering emails *after 2019-12-31* and *before 2021-01-01*.  Results are OK.

But then, when I select all those emails and that I move them to the local folder, they are not removed from the server (nor the virtual folder).

Is this a bug ? Can someone help me ?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you using POP or IMAP? If you use IMAP, the downloaded emails will not be removed from remote server.

Comment: IMAP. Then how can I do ?

Comment: [Changing IMAP to POP with Thunderbird 3 and above](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/changing-imap-pop)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete mail from server after download with IMAP using Thunderbird?](https://superuser.com/questions/944995/how-to-delete-mail-from-server-after-download-with-imap-using-thunderbird)